# Obtener coordenadas de un pixel con OpenCV - Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, cv2

Buenas, estoy tratando de obtener la coordenada en **X** (el número de columna) para el/los píxel/es que cumplan una condición dada (ejemplo **RGB = 255,0,0**) y para un valor de **Y** (fila) dado.

[image: aquí un ejemplo]

Existe alguna manera de hacerlo en Python usando OpenCV?

Comment: Hola @Facundo, normalmente este tipo de preguntas que parecen una tarea académica (no digo que lo sea) suelen ser rechazadas por la comunidad si no vienen acompañadas con el código de lo que has intentado hacer hasta ahora, te invito a que lo incluyas simplemente editando tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Existe, lo acabo de ver en la documentación de OpenCV.